# How to explicit typecast an ENUM type in a LIKE search?

Tags: postgresql, enums, typecast-operator

Today I'm facing an interesting issue with Postgres and I can't find a straight solution.

I made a custom ENUM type like:

```
CREATE TYPE public.type_emergency_status AS ENUM
('OPEN', 'OPEN.ATTENDED', 'OPEN.DEFERRED', 'ABANDONED', 'CLOSED.CANCELED', 'CLOSED.RESOLVED', 'CLOSED.UNRESOLVED');
```

In my table, I have defined a field as this type.
Now, I want to find all the records with emergency_status LIKE 'CLOSED%'

If I make a simple query like:

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE <field> LIKE 'CLOSED%'
```

And obtain:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: type_emergency_status ~~ unknown
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

The question is, **where do I do the explicit cast?**

I have tried several ways, but haven't found where to do thad.

Any DB expert on this?

Answer (score 4):

To make it more safe and index friendly:

```
SELECT *
FROM <table_name>
WHERE <field> in (
    select enumlabel::type_emergency_status
    from pg_enum
    where enumtypid = 'type_emergency_status'::regtype and enumlabel like 'CLOSED%');
```

Comment: Great! Both solutions worked fine. 
I will take @Abelisto 's answer as correct 'cause it's index friendly.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`SELECT * FROM <TABLE_NAME> WHERE <field>::text ILIKE 'CLOSED%';`